# Load flash from JavaScript with Object Tag

Tags: javascript, html, flash, html-object

I tried to load flash (swf file) either from external sources or local sources,

I use object tag in html to contain the flash for some reason,
if I load the flash directly in the object tag, it will work flawlessly, like this:

```
<object height="100" width="100" data="helloworld.swf" id="flash"></object>
```

Next, I need to load the flash dynamically from JavaScript, but several problems arise:

```
var flash=document.getElementById("flash");
flash.setAttribute("data","helloworld.swf");
```

the code above works fine in Chrome, but it doesn't do anything in IE (my IE is IE11 on windows 8)

If I modify the object tag to iframe tag, then it works, but I need it to be object tag,

Any solutions come to mind?

Comment: So why not use `var flash=document.getElementById("object");` instead of `var flash=document.getElementById("flash");`?

Comment: There's no DOM element with "object" as the ID

Comment: Ow sorry, I was thinking of `createElement`. Try cloning and replacing it. Flash is very persistent.

Answer (score 3):

You can force the refresh by readding the object:

```
var flash = document.getElementById("flash");
flash.setAttribute("data","helloworld.swf");

var clone = flash.cloneNode(true);
flash.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, flash);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SWFObject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/). It will save you from all the cross-browser compatibility troubles.